# Spring Schedule Состояние потока при повторном использовании

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring

TaskScheduler позволяет запускать Runnable task с определённой переодичностью, и у меня вопрос, с каким состоянием запускаеться данный поток второй и третий раз ?
Например если у меня есть класс реализующий Runnable, и будет хранить поле с int которое будет увеличиваться на один после каждого запуска метода run, после 10 выполнений потока, какое значение будет иметь данная переменная ?

Comment: Поток просто вызывает метод run. Если 10 раз запустить поток, а метод run увеличивает значение на 1, то будет 10

Comment: А можно узнать где это объяснялось ? Меня просто беспокоит что я нигде не нашёл этого в документации, что это именно так и работает.

Comment: Не знаю даже. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html     When an object implementing interface Runnable is used to create a thread, starting the thread causes the object's run method to be called in that separately executing thread.